# Using Sql Server 2012 developer with VS2012 instead of the built in express edition

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-2012

If I want to install a full fledged developer edition of SQl Server 2012 with my existing VS2012 Pro installation, do I have to get rid of the express edition of Sql server that comes in bundled with VS2012 Pro edition? I plan to use the developer edition instead of the one that comes in packaged with VS2012.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can have both installed.

Comment: Hey, Thanks.. but is there an installation order to follow like installing sql 2012 first followed by vs2012 since i already have vs2012 installed..?

Comment: It really shouldn't matter at all. Ultimately, no matter how you install it, or where its installed (locally or remote), changes to your web.config file will point you at whatever sql server you want to test/develop against.

Comment: Okay, Thanks for the help.. appreciate it!!